# responsive flexbox layout image overflow footer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I made some site and use flexbox for decorate layout.

Page structure is simple. Just 3 tags.

`<header>`

`<section>`

`<footer>`

[index.html]

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header__left">
      <span>Email here or call</span>
    </div>
    <div class="header__center">
      <img src="img/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="header__right">
      <a href="#">About us</a>
      <a href="#">Our Work</a>
      <a href="#">Our People</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
  </section>
  <footer>
    THIS IS FOOTER
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[style.css]

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
}
.header__left {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.header__center {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.header__right {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
section img {
  max-width: 25vw;
}
```

And defined `max-width: 25vw;` to display 4 images on 1 row.

When I enterd the site, It looks like this.

[image]

If browser was small, it works perfectly.

But when I increase browser size,

[image]

`<section>` invade `<footer>`

Is there any way to prevent it?

Thanks.

Comment: After remove `max-height: 100vh;` it works fine. But, is there any another solution here, please comment it.

Comment: You could use bootstrap as well to achieve responsive design layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out! 
Just you have to alter the height and width to 100%
https://jsfiddle.net/ksmLwngp/4/

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
}
.header__left {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.header__center {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.header__right {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
section img {
  max-width: 25vw;
}

  .imgbox {
 width:100%;
   height: 100%;
  }

<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header__left">
      <span>Email here or call</span>
    </div>
    <div class="header__center">
      <img src="img/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="header__right">
      <a href="#">About us</a>
      <a href="#">Our Work</a>
      <a href="#">Our People</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
  <div class="imgbox">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    <img src="./img/dummy.jpg" alt="Sample photo">
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    THIS IS FOOTER
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `max-height: 100vh;` example on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8v196pm/2/)

Comment: on the mobile your section with img has height more than 100vh